# Android gives me `OutOfMemoryException` when loading images from web in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, out-of-memory

I am using this `ArrayAdapter` to load thumbnail images asynchronously

```
public class CourierArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Courier> {
    private Map<String, Bitmap> bitmaps = new HashMap<>();

    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView txtViewName;
        TextView txtViewNumber;
        CircleImageView imageViewPic;
        int position;
    }

    public CourierArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Courier> requests) {
        super(context, -1, requests);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        Courier request = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_courier, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_list_item_courier_name);
            viewHolder.txtViewNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_list_item_courier_number);
            viewHolder.imageViewPic = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_list_item_courier_pic);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txtViewName.setText(request.name);
        viewHolder.txtViewNumber.setText(request.number);
        viewHolder.position = position;

        if (bitmaps.containsKey(request.picURL)) {
            viewHolder.imageViewPic.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(request.picURL));
        }
        else
            new LoadImageTask(position, viewHolder).execute(request.picURL);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        private int mPosition;
        private ViewHolder mViewHolder;


        public LoadImageTask(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
            this.mPosition = position;
            this.mViewHolder = holder;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]); // create URL for image

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    bitmaps.put(params[0], bitmap);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect(); // close the HttpURLConnection
            }

            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (mViewHolder.position == mPosition)
                mViewHolder.imageViewPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am loading these images using a `picURL` property and I am loading them using a private `AsyncTask` class. The problem is that I get `OutOfMemoryException` an this error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 37602252 byte allocation with 16776720 free bytes and 29MB until OOM
      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:863)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:839)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:877)
      at net.faraznet.provider.arrayadapters.CourierArrayAdapter$LoadImageTask.doInBackground(CourierArrayAdapter.java:99)
      at net.faraznet.provider.arrayadapters.CourierArrayAdapter$LoadImageTask.doInBackground(CourierArrayAdapter.java:76)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The images are a bit large in size and if possible, it is not an issue that I resize them before loading them into memory, but the problem is that I don't know how to achieve this task or any other solutions to my problem

Comment: Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load images. It is quite easy to implement and will handle OOM :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: You can use Glide than Picasso. Glide is more efficient in performance and memory management. check this https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: @SripadRaj Glide is much more better than Picasso. You can check the link I specified for performance comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a third party library named [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)  , which is recommended by google . To add this library , add the the following dependency in your build.gradle file , in module app .

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

And then you can simply load image in following way

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(request.picURL)
    .into(viewHolder.imageViewPic);
```

Comment: how can I cache them into my bitmaps `HashMap`? Since I want to load images only once?  does this library do this by itself?

Comment: Glide has the option to cache . just add diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) . So  it will be Glide.with(context)
    .load(request.picURL)
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(viewHolder.imageViewPic);

Comment: I don't mean that kind of caching.For example I have images p1,p2, and p3. And in my listview the p3 image repeats itself two times. I want the bitmap that Glide loaded and reuse it. I don't want to call Glide method twice

Comment: sorry , I am not sure about that .

Answer (score 1):

If you can use custom libraries, then use `Glide`.

Glide is more efficient in performance and memory management with respect to Images  than `Picasso`. check this [comparison](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)

All the steps are clearly defined in [github](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to use Glide in application

Alternatively you can increase heap size of application by [android:largeHeap="true"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) . But this will not work on any pre Honeycomb devices

On pre 2.3 devices, you can use the VMRuntime class.  but this will not work on Gingerbread and above.

```
VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(BIGGER_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in dependencies.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and below code to get the image in ImageView.

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.into(imageView)
```

And you are good to go. For more information, check this [link](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Answer (score 0):

recently i have achieved this, so the best way to achieve this use Picasso, user this code in your array adapter

```
Picasso.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
            /* Save the bitmap or do something with it here */

                    //Set it in the ImageView

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }
            });
```

Use this in manifest before Application.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Add the following line in dependencies or Gradle.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

for information go through the following links

http://square.github.io/picasso/

https://github.com/square/picasso

i hope it will helpful.